# Similar method of getPageWidth in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I am working on horizontal image slider with recycler view. In my previous app, i implemented **PagerAdapter** so that i can safely use getPageWidth(0.8f). Now I see no easy option in **RecyclerView.Adapter**. Is there any implementation which i could gain the same result ? Thanks

**Previous image slider** ( PagerAdapter ) inside each row of listView

[image]